# Send an equation to another android user for solving auto

Tags: android

I want to create in my app a button that when the user press that button the app will then prompt the contact list, the user will choose one of his contacts and the app automatically send equation to that contact.

The contact will receive this equation in his device and his device will solve the equation and when it will be solved the user will get a massage from the contact.

I would like to hear your idea's on the way to  send the equation and receive when the equation has been solved only!!!

Note:
1. Any of the users should not see this equation. 
2. I'm assuming both users have the same app.
3. I want to make the receiving and sending in the same app. (Client/Server)

Thanks!

Comment: Im still in thinking proccess... thats why im asking ... I want to hear your ideas if it is possible.

Comment: i think you can ask in the some other discussion forms, here you will only get help if you are facing difficulty in code(programming)

Comment: I edited my equestion ... my problem is with send the equation and receive when the equation has been solved only...

Comment: do first of all do you tried client/server communication in android for sending msg

Comment: Well .. the thing with client/server is the main issue because i need to send only the equation without the other user to see it... something like an auto message in the background. can you understand my problem ? thanks..

Comment: yes, check this,http://www.academia.edu/4839374/Study_on_client_server_interaction_in_an_android_Smartphone_messaging_application_through_prototype_implementation

Comment: Thanks i read this but the ducumant is very general... and his approach is for IM communication.. i'm not into chat app but just to send this equation i want once without text messaging