# How to send data to another android device

Tags: android

I want that my app will send data (Equation) to another android device and when the other device will get that data he will make calculation with that data (equation).

any idea's how to send data ??

Thanks.

P.s: its similar to this preview question: [Send an equation to another android user for solving auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468427/send-an-equation-to-another-android-user-for-solving-auto/)

Comment: you can use Google push messaging service

Comment: Thanks for the comment ... is that Google Cloud Messaging for Android?

Comment: yes read this article http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Thanks i read it but didnt understood if the client will see this data or he will get that data in the background while the users wont notice it ( thats what i need ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GCM. it's the Android push notification.
The notifications will arrive to the device regardless if the app is in the background or forground. 
About the user noticing it, it's up you. The push notification itself is not showing anything to the user. It enters a callback (OnReceive) and you as the developer decides what to do with it. you can show an alert at the status bar, Send a broadcast to a service, update the DB or in your case do something with an equation etc...

Comment: Exellent information thanks. So with GCM i will be able to send an equation to the user i want and to program on a callbkack ( OnReceive ) that his device will solve the equation and get the result back ??

Comment: You can send Strings.  Then in the OnReceive you will need to pars the equation and solve it. So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you considering Bluetooth as an option?

If so, this lib may help you https://github.com/buddles/AndBT

Comment: Bluetooth will be difficult because im talking about huge distances but thanks!

Comment: Got it! That'd be good to have this condition in the problem definition ;)